# query inside query to 1 query postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, serialization

i have a query like this

```
UPDATE FOLLOWUP F SET CUSTOMER=(SELECT NAME FROM CUSTOMERS C WHERE F.CUST_ID=C.ID), PHONE=(SELECT SEARCHKEY FROM CUSTOMERS C WHERE F.CUST_ID=C.ID);
```

this is succesfully working in my postgresql, but not running in java

and my java function

```
for (final TicketLineInfo l : ticket.getLines())
    if(l.getConsumption()!= 0.0 && l.getMultiply()!=l.getConsumption()) {            
        new PreparedSentence(s
                , "UPDATE FOLLOWUP F SET CUSTOMER=(SELECT NAME FROM CUSTOMERS C WHERE F.CUST_ID=?), PHONE=(SELECT SEARCHKEY FROM CUSTOMERS C WHERE F.CUST_ID=?);"
                , SerializerWriteParams.INSTANCE
                ).exec(new DataParams() { public void writeValues() throws BasicException {
                        setString(1, ticket.getCustomerId());
                        setString(2, ticket.getCustomerId());
                }});
                 }
```

when i run this

i get error like this:

```
com.openbravo.basic.BasicException: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

my question is how do i convert the above query into one single query without a subquery.. so that i can avoid this exception and proceed with my execution OR is there any other serializer which supports this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't need subqueries in your query:

```
update FOLLOWUP as F set
    Name = c.Name,
    Phone = c.SearchKey
from CUSTOMERS as c
where
    F.Cust_ID = C.ID and
    F.Cust_ID = ?
```